# Python script works run from dir but not as CLI cmd, despite setting $PATH and shebang

Tags: python, linux, bash, command-line

**Please skip straight to EDIT 3 for the cause of this problem (end of this post)**

TL;DR — the editor did not save the shebang line, though I'm not sure why.

---

I've made a script that just cleans the download folder up (it was a learning thing mainly). However, I can't get it to work as a CLI cmd.

If I run the script from the directory that it's in, it's fine and does what I want

```
vco@geoHP:~/bin$ python3 clean_downloads.py
```

That works fine.

The first line on the script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Which as far as I can tell is correct?

Then in my .bashrc I have at the bottom of the file :

```
119 # Modify the existing variable 'PATH'
120 # 'export' means make this available globally, instead of just for this file    . 
121 
122 export PATH=$PATH:/home/vco/bin
```

Which is also what seems to be needed?

So when I try and run this script from a terminal I get (after a couple of minutes) an error :

```
vco@geoHP:~$ clean_downloads.py
from: too many arguments
/home/vco/bin/clean_downloads.py: line 24: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
/home/vco/bin/clean_downloads.py: line 24: `    }'
vco@geoHP:~$
```

So I'm not sure why that is, as I said the script runs fine when it's run from the directory that it's in... I googled the error and it seems to be Bash, rather than the Python syntax errors.

So I guess that it's trying to run my script in bash instead of Python?

Any help fixing / working this out appreciated.

[here's a link to the script if needed, not sure if its relevant though](http://pastebin.com/ke8k6jeX)

---

EDIT - 1

@Andrew - I ran the command

```
vco@geoHP:~$ bash --norc --noprofile PATH=/home/vco/bin clean_downloads.py
```

and got

```
vco@geoHP:~$ bash --norc --noprofile PATH=/home/vco/bin clean_downloads.py
bash: PATH=/home/vco/bin: No such file or directory
vco@geoHP:~$
```

---

EDIT 2 -

The script is set to execute -

```
vco@geoHP:~/bin$ ls -l
total 16
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vco vco 1699 Sep 29 22:36 clean_downloads.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vco vco 2184 Oct  3 14:47 functions.py
drwxrwxr-x 2 vco vco 4096 Sep 20 18:24 logs
-rwx------ 1 vco vco  479 Sep 21 18:34 pythonRsync.py
vco@geoHP:~/bin$
```

This is the result of an `ls` in the `/usr/bin` directory to check that `python3` is in there:

```
vco@geoHP:/usr/bin$ ls | grep python3
dh_python3
idle-python3.4
python3
python3.4
python3.4m
python3m
vco@geoHP:/usr/bin$
```

---

EDIT 3 -

I found the problem! Thanks for all the help; for some reason Sublime Text wasn't actually adding the shebang?! I've no idea how this works (or didn't work), but I opened up the file in Gedit and VIM and the shebang wasn't on the first line, I'd definitely saved the file in Sublime. I also double checked that it had been saved, and that it didn't work. So this is very odd to me, I'm not sure if anyone knows why this would be?

I would put this as an answer to this post, but I'm not sure what the reasons are and can't really explain much about it, perhaps someone else knows why something like this could happen?

Thanks for the suggestions though everyone :)

Comment: What happens if you run it from a bash started without any config, e.g.: `bash --norc --noprofile` then run `PATH=/home/vco/bin clean_downloads.py`

Comment: not sure I've never heard of that before, so what would I put into the command line? `bash --norc --noprofile PATH=/home/vco/bin clean_downloads.py` ? cheers

Comment: @Andrew - I just ran that command - edited the OP with the results... basically it just said there was no file or directory? Not sure if that's a problem with the way I ran it or not though, cheers

Comment: A `PATH` value like that is going to cause problems if that script expects to be able to execute any external commands.

Comment: Are you sure that the `python3` you're running is the one in `/usr/bin` ?

Comment: @EtanReisner - not sure I follow what you mean there... the path value in the OP or the one from @Andrew?

Comment: @MarkReed - not sure, I don't really follow you. It's just python3, no? I checked that it's where I said it was on the PATH line and it is. `vco@geoHP:/usr/bin$ ls | grep python3
dh_python3
idle-python3.4
python3
python3.4
python3.4m
python3m
vco@geoHP:/usr/bin$ `

Comment: @Andrew, since the PATH would be exported during the command's _execution_, not during the lookup prior, I'm not sure that would do what you want.

Comment: @user3130747 -- there's a lot here that's OS and permision-dependent that your sysadmin is better placed to debug than we are. For instance, it's possible on Linux for `/home` (or any other filesystem) to be mounted with the `noexec` filesystem flag, preventing *any* files on that partition from being treated as executable. It's possible for SELinux to be blocking execution. It's possible for... well, the point I'm making is, **lots** of things are possible.

Comment: ...that said, getting shell errors certainly does look like your shebang isn't being honored. If your executable permissions are set... hmm. Check that your script is saved as a UNIX-formatted text file, not a DOS-formatted one; otherwise, it would be trying to use `/usr/bin/python3$'\r'` as an executable (treating the CR character in the newline as part of the filename).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - hi - it's my own machine, running Ubuntu... Perhaps there was something at set up like what you mentioned? I don't remember anything though... It's definitely not a DOS formatted file, it's only ever been in my system. cheers

Comment: Only having existed on your system is not an indication that it is not a DOS file. It could absolutely have been created that way (or converted) by accident. Try running dos2unix on it just to be safe?

Comment: @EtanReisner - thanks, I should have given more info, I wrote it from the start though... cheers for the help, I've found out the problem and added it to the OP... Basically Sublime text wasn't saving the shebang at the start of the file for some reason, I don't understand why...

Comment: What does `type -p python3` say? What about `ls -l /usr/bin/python3`? What about `file "$(readlink -m /usr/bin/python3)"`?

Comment: @EtanReisner  Heres the output from those two commands


    `vco@geoHP:~$ type -p python3`
    `/usr/bin/python3`
    `vco@geoHP:~$ `






`vco@geoHP:~$ file "$(readlink -m /usr/bin/python3)"
/usr/bin/python3.4: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=d5e259fafd544d60296196e5f91d6b2f7eb2715d, stripped
vco@geoHP:~$`

Comment: Given the answer those questions weren't really relevant anymore but thanks anyway. I can't imagine any reason sublime text wouldn't save that line though (other than you not hitting save). Can you reproduce this behaviour?

Comment: @EtanReisner - no it seems I can't... I just tried it with a simple hello world script and it worked, I really did check though... I'm really sorry if it's been a big time waste :/

Answer (score 1):

Your script isn't set to be executable. As such the shebang line isn't being used and your shell is falling back to trying to run the script itself.

You need to set the script to be executable. `chmod 755 clean_downloads.py`.

Comment: I can't replicate behaviour that on Linux nor Mac. I get "permission denied" on both.

Comment: @Etan Its set to execute - `vco@geoHP:~/bin$ ls -l
total 16
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vco vco 1699 Sep 29 22:36 clean_downloads.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vco vco 2184 Oct  3 14:47 functions.py
drwxrwxr-x 2 vco vco 4096 Sep 20 18:24 logs
-rwx------ 1 vco vco  479 Sep 21 18:34 pythonRsync.py
vco@geoHP:~/bin$ 
`

Answer (score 0):

You also can create an alias in your .bashrc file:

```
alias "clean_downloads=python3 /home/vco/bin/clean_downloads.py"
```

This does the job.

Comment: hey Oscar - yeah this works but it doesn't address what's going on with all the other stuff. Thanks, but I'd like to try and work out why the other stuff isn't working too